Sticky header overlay not working on mobile (iOS)
I'm building an Angular client page with a header consisting of a title row .navbar-header and a tablist row .navbar-tabs, the latter being set as sticky. So when I scroll, the header is supposed to scroll with the page, until the tablist row gets looked at the top.
On desktop browsers this is working just as expected. But on my phone (iOS / Safari and Firefox) it isn't: The content frame is overlapping the header completely. Also, the content frame consists of several material cards, some of which are visually behind the header, some are ahead. But either case, I cannot click the header frame.

Here is my html:
<body>
  <app-root ng-version="17.3.3">
    <app-navbar>
      <nav class="navbar-header">
        <h1 class="navbar-title">Psychotherapie? Mangelware!</h1>
        <h3 class="navbar-subtitle">#fairchair</h3>
      </nav>
      <nav
        mat-tab-nav-bar=""
        class="mat-mdc-tab-nav-bar mat-mdc-tab-header navbar-tabs mat-mdc-tab-nav-bar-stretch-tabs mat-primary _mat-animation-noopable"
        role="tablist"
      ></nav>
    </app-navbar>
  </app-root>
</body>

encapsulation of my navbar component is set to ViewEncapsulation.Emulated.
navbar.component.css is looking like this:
:host {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.navbar-tabs {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

And I have the following global style rules:
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

UPDATE
This seems to be related, but it did not help me. Setting
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

instead of using 100vh doesn't solve the problem.

This is not a duplicate of question #72830064, see my update.

Fixed by splitting app-navbar into one header node and one navbar node.
